# Need help with a script

Tags: magento-1, javascript, sales-order, script

So I have this script:

```
<?php     
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);

Mage::app();

/* Set our dates */
$fromDate = '2016-05-30 00:00:00';
$toDate = '2019-05-31 00:00:00';

/* Get the collection. Here we set a date range, and ignore cancelled orders. 
   You can filter the collection however you prefer */
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled')));

/* Here you can build an array, write to a CSV etc */
foreach($orders as $order){
    /* get order details (e.g. ID) like this: */
     echo $order->getIncrementId().'<br/>';
    $id = $order->getIncrementId()

    /* you can load the order items, if you need them */
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();    
}
```

I am trying to place this in the root of my server so I can run it and print orders to the screen. What should the file extension be .js .php .sh? Also once it's on the root of the server, how can I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that code in a PHP file (let's say test.php) and run that file directly from browser like this.

```
your.site.url/test.php
```

Note: Following two line are unnecessary for what you want to achieve

```
$id = $order->getIncrementId()

    /* you can load the order items, if you need them */
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

I'd recommend removing these line because you just want to get the all order ids from that time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in **shell** and after that you execute it via a command line.

First you create a new file in : `shell/my_script.php`

Add the code bellow on it :

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class My_Script extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Your script content her
    }

    // Useful for the script's help message
    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
        Usage:  php -f my_script.php -- [options]

        by_date   Sort products by discount ending date
        help       This help

        USAGE;
    }
}

// Here we should instantiate the class to call the script
$shell = new My_Script();
$shell->run();
```

Now you execute the script like this: `$ php -f shell/my_script.php`

Comment: How would I see the output of that file? The output is basically a bunch of sales orders.

Comment: You output it in a console not in a file